# How do you shrinkwrap part of a mesh to another mesh with a smooth falloff?

Tags: sculpting, shrinkwrap, project

In ZBrush, there is an option called Project All which basically works as a shrinkwrap modifier and projects the low poly to high poly to get the details
In order to do that in blender, the way I know how is to use the shrinkwrap modifier

The problem with the shrinkwrap modifier is that it projects all of the mesh, and, I want to project a part of the mesh to high poly model to recover the details.
I know that we could use vertex groups and link it to the shrinkwrap modifier to project the only portion we need to the high poly

But with that method, the falloff is still harsh
I want the falloff to be as smooth as possible

Is there any way I could achieve that?
If you don't understand my question clearly,  I could try and put up some screenshots.
But please do help me find a solution....

Comment: you can smooth the vertex group, this way the falloff will be smoothed

Comment: @moonboots Could you please tell me how do I smooth the vertex groups?
Inside weight paint mode I tried "Weights --> Smooth" but it wasn't working well. Is there any other way?

Comment: Once you've done Weights > Smooth go into the Operator Box and increase the iterations value