# Nose mask customized to 3D scanned faces, we want the edge of the mask to change depending on the face used

Tags: geometry-nodes, shrinkwrap

We are trying to make a model for a mask that we can fit perfectly to different faces. In the pictures below you can see that we have marked a black area, that should touch the skin on the face. We want to use the same mask model but the black area should change and that the blue area should remain the same for a different nose. Right now we create the mask using shrink wrap to adjust it to the face and sculpt it afterwards to get the details we want. When we change to a different face, we want to use the same model, but right now we can't adjust the mask the same way. The whole mask deforms when using shrink wrap again, look at the last picture below. We don’t want to redo the entire model to each nose and wonder if anyone knows a way to adjust only the edge of the model depending on the face scan we’re using.

We want the black area to touch the skin, the blue area is the breathing area so that part of the mask has to stay the same for any type of nose and it should not touch the skin. We also don't want the tubes on the side of the mask to deform, you can see the tubes in the first picture.

We're grateful for all help!

Our sample file:
[image]

[image: picture of blender and mask on the nose]
[image: another face, same mask from profile]
[image: from above]
[image: how we want it from profile]
[image: from the front, how we want it]
[image: the nose mask]
[image: warped mask wrong]

Comment: Having the undeformed mask shape would help here. Can you upload a sample file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Could you provide a picture with another face scan but the same mask illustrating (just with arrows ?) what should change and what should be unmodified ? I do not understand "the middle part of the mask has to have the same distance to the nose". Is it perpendicular to the skin ?

Comment: @StefLAncien we added pictures and drawings of the nose mask on a different person. The distance between the nose and the mask is not perpendicual.

Comment: @lemon we uploaded a sample file on the website you linked.

Comment: @Jess, once uploaded you may obtain a link: this link should be pasted in your question

Comment: @lemon thanks! It's now uploaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

The *Shrinkwrap* modifier can be restricted to the *Vertex Group* assigned to the modifiable part. The *Wrap Method* is set to *Project* along *Z axis* (local axis of the object the modifier is added to):

[image: Face 2 with mask]

Smoothing the *Vertex Group Weight* might help to smooth the projection (see [How do you shrinkwrap part of a mesh to another mesh with a smooth falloff?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303828/how-do-you-shrinkwrap-part-of-a-mesh-to-another-mesh-with-a-smooth-falloff)):

[image: Weight paint]
[image: Weight paint results]

Comment: thank you so much, that really helped us!

Comment: May I recommend to apply this : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)